# Apache redirect not working when there is a file there

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

I am using the following regular expression:

```
^/(.*)/(?i:audaud)(.*)$
```

This works, redirecting any "audaud" or "AUDAUD" etc to the page I want.  The problem arrives when I try to access the file which is at /catalog/AUDAUD.html.  Whenever I do this, I get a 404.

Would anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: It seems an older mod_rewrite rule I wrote to direct to a php was intercepting the request before my mod_alias.  That explains its odd behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add a negative lookahead to exclude the file:

```
^/(.*)/(?!AUDAUD\.html$)(?i:audaud)(.*)$
```

The negative lookahead `(?!AUDAUD\.html$)` asserts that what follows is not `AUDAUD.html$` and the end of the string.

Another option would be to include the whole path in a negative lookahead at the beginning of the regex:

```
^(?!/catalog/AUDAUD\.html$)/(.*)/(?i:audaud)(.*)$
```

Comment: This is a quick fix, but if you want more precise tweaks (which I'm sure can be provided, please show the entire redirect).